# SourceTree cloning git repo always aborting

Tags: git, macos, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

SourceTree repo cloning ends up with the error:
 **"abort: repository git@bitbucket.org:*ammar*/android.git not found"**.
I've done the ssh also of that account and the repository is listing down but they are not cloning,

Even the GitHub repositories I've done with the PAT are listed but the cloning error is the same.

I've reinstalled the source tree but the same error does so. however, when I get a cloned repo via terminal git and then add it to the source tree, everything is fine just for that repo, like push, pull, etc. working well.

Anybody suggestions or updates will be great for me. Thank you

[After Cloning I'm getting this image response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXvDM.png)

[image]

Comment: And one more thing I'm also unable to install command line tools for the source tree every time it says failed.

Comment: Repository not found, you don't give source tree the correct path for URL repository.

Comment: @Eng_Farghly I've manually put that but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

> And one more thing I'm also unable to install command line tools for the source tree every time it says failed.

Two issues could be relevant here:

- [SRCTREE-3172](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-3172): Possible workaround:
  Run this command in the terminal:

  ```
  alias stree='/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/stree'
  ```

  Right after running this command, the command tool should work.
  Users can use it by just typing `stree` in the terminal and see if it opens up SourceTree.
  Or to be more specific: `stree /path/to/repo` to see if it opens up a repository.
- [SRCTREE-7794](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-7794):  it seems that all that the GUI is doing when you install the command-line tool is creating a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`.
  The error arises when `/usr/local` is not owned by the current user, which is very possible, and really shouldn't be assumed by the GUI.

  Anyway, the easy solution to create the symlink is to run the following from the shell.

  ```
  sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/stree" /usr/local/bin/
  ```

  Of course, this only needs to be done once, and will persist through updates.

Check then if the issue persists when cloning a Git repository from sourceTree.

Comment: After running both of the commands I'm still facing the issue on command line installation.

Comment: and the aborting is also the aborting of cloning repo is there, please what the issue is.

Comment: @Ammar Are you running Source Tree as root? If not, do you see the symlink (symbolic link) "`stree`' created in /usr/local/bin, and referencing `/Applications/Sourcetree.app/Contents/Resources/stree`? (do a `ls -alrth` in `/usr/local/bin`)